# Inserting multiple rows to database table from a form

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a checklist form that managers can fill out. And at the bottom, they type out a material list that their employees can sign off on when complete. The amount of materials can be as long as 20+ rows. Below is what the rows they fill out contain:

```
        <tr><td><button type="button" class="addRow">Add Row</button></td></tr>
        <tr><th>WO# / Date <br/>(if added or changed after Revision 1)<th>Component Name and Number</th><th>Finish Sizes</th><th>Material</th><th>Total # Pieces</th><th>Work Order</th><th>Notes</th><th>Work Order</th><th>Notes</th><th>Work Order</th><th>Notes</th></tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name='wo_num_and_date'/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='comp_name_and_num'/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='finish_sizes'/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='material'/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='total_num_pieces'/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='workorder_num_one'/></td>
            <td><textarea rows="2" cols="12" name='notes_one'></textarea></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='workorder_num_two'/></td>
            <td><textarea rows="2" cols="12" name='notes_two'></textarea></td>
            <td><input type="text" name='workorder_num_three'/></td>
            <td><textarea rows="2" cols="12" name='notes_three'></textarea></td>
        </tr>
```

It starts out with just 1 fillable row and then I've got some jquery that allows them to add more rows.

My insert script below is only inserting the first row in my form.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $user = getuserinfo($loggedin_id);
   $posted_date = $_POST['posted_date'];
   $revision = $_POST['revision'];
   $per_wo_num = $_POST['per_wo_num'];
   $category = $_POST['category'];

   $wo_num_and_date = $_POST['wo_num_and_date'];
   $comp_name_and_num = $_POST['comp_name_and_num'];
   $finish_sizes = $_POST['finish_sizes'];
   $material = $_POST['material'];
   $total_num_pieces = $_POST['total_num_pieces'];
   $workorder_num_one = $_POST['workorder_num_one'];
   $notes_one = $_POST['notes_one'];
   $workorder_num_two = $_POST['workorder_num_two'];
   $notes_two = $_POST['notes_two'];
   $workorder_num_three = $_POST['workorder_num_three'];
   $notes_three = $_POST['notes_three'];


$sql = "INSERT INTO checklist_revision (job_num, user_id, revision_num, category, posted_date, per_workorder_number)
VALUES ($job_num,
        $loggedin_id,
        $revision,
        $category,
        STR_TO_DATE('$posted_date', '%Y-%m-%d'),
        $per_wo_num);";

 mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql);


$revision_id = mysqli_insert_id($dbc3);

$sql2 = "INSERT INTO checklist_component_stock (revision, job_num, category, posted_date, wo_num_and_date, comp_name_and_number, finish_sizes, material, total_num_pieces, workorder_num_one, notes_one, signoff_user_one, workorder_num_two, notes_two, signoff_user_two, workorder_num_three, notes_three, signoff_user_three)
VALUES ('$revision_id',
        '$job_num',
        '$category',
        STR_TO_DATE('$posted_date', '%Y-%m-%d'),
        '$wo_num_and_date',
        '$comp_name_and_num',
        '$finish_sizes',
        '$material',
        '$total_num_pieces',
        '$workorder_num_one',
        '$notes_one',
        NULL,
        '$workorder_num_two',
        '$notes_two',
        NULL,
        '$workorder_num_three',
        '$notes_three',
        NULL);";

 mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql2);
```

How do I make it so no matter how many rows they add, it inserts them all into the table instead of just the first row?

VAR DUMP after trying Huseyin's answer:

```
array (size=17)
  'submit' => string 'Submit!' (length=7)
  'posted_date' => string '2014-04-07' (length=10)
  'category' => string '1' (length=1)
  'revision' => string '4' (length=1)
  'revisionDate' => string '2014-04-07' (length=10)
  'per_wo_num' => string '2' (length=1)
  'wo_num_and_date' => string 'WO#5/2013-04-04' (length=15)
  'comp_name_and_num' => string 'Lift 2' (length=6)
  'finish_sizes' => string '2x2x2' (length=5)
  'material' => string 'P20' (length=3)
  'total_num_pieces' => string '1' (length=1)
  'workorder_num_one' => string '1' (length=1)
  'notes_one' => string 'OK' (length=2)
  'workorder_num_two' => string '2' (length=1)
  'notes_two' => string 'OK' (length=2)
  'workorder_num_three' => string '3' (length=1)
  'notes_three' => string 'NOT OK' (length=6)
```

Comment: Your code is wide-open to sql injections!

Comment: @AleksG is 100000% correct. The web is like swiss cheese with security holes, please don't add to them. Use a framework, that'll secure things. You just never know when "Mr Johnny ' DROP ALL TABLES" decides to use your form.

Comment: @ScottMcGready I think all he needs to do is use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` on the POST object or use parameterized queries?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger Sure but as this is a snippet of code I'm assuming there's more potential holes (or the code may grow in the future, creating further holes) where a framework would sort this problem from the get go. It takes a few minutes to setup a lightweight framework that could save precious hours down the line.

Comment: I knew someone would say something before I even posted. I'm all about it and will secure it as soon as its working properly as this is an internal web app. @ScottMcGready I know part of this application is built using a framework but I'm new in this position and the professional world and the only developer so I'm learning as I go, thanks for your suggestion though I'm certainly going that route soon!

Comment: @MikeOscarEcho I appreciate that you're new but understand that you're creating security holes that are costing your company money. You need to start with a secure method (not secure it as soon as it's working properly as there's never any time for that). The moment you get a prototype working management will shift you to the next thing and your test code will become production and you'll be supporting it for the rest of your career there. Don't mean to drag you down but please do realise that starting with the right mindset is half the battle.

Comment: @ScottMcGready You're right. I guess I just decided to stick with what I'm comfortable with and the fact that I have a tight deadline to get this up I'm just rushing to get it working really. I really do appreciate your input though and will start learning the framework the old dev started using (silex).

Comment: @MikeOscarEcho there's never enough time ;). Look man, I've learned the hard way (as most of the guys here have too) and you wish you could go back and tell yourself to do it differently. Live and learn I suppose but the comment about management is far truer than you'd imagine. Prototypes = release candidates in management's eyes, remember that. I wish I had!

Comment: @ScottMcGready Haha you're actually so right.. The last 2 or 3 features I implemented I was asked to put them out as soon as possible because they were vital to the operation of the company, in my eyes they were all still in testing. One specifically, I put out and knew it was buggy as hell, a day later I got complaints that something wasn't working, which I anticipated and was ready for. I hate it lol. Anyway thanks for your advice man!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use array notationed names in form and implement following;

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name='wo_num_and_date[]'/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name='comp_name_and_num[]'/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name='finish_sizes[]'/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name='material[]'/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name='total_num_pieces[]'/></td>
    <td><input type="text" name='workorder_num_one[]'/></td>
    <td><textarea rows="2" cols="12" name='notes_one[]'></textarea></td>
    <td><input type="text" name='workorder_num_two[]'/></td>
    <td><textarea rows="2" cols="12" name='notes_two[]'></textarea></td>
    <td><input type="text" name='workorder_num_three[]'/></td>
    <td><textarea rows="2" cols="12" name='notes_three[]'></textarea></td>
</tr>
```

And in php;

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $user = getuserinfo($loggedin_id);
       $posted_date = $_POST['posted_date'];
       $revision = $_POST['revision'];
       $per_wo_num = $_POST['per_wo_num'];
       $category = $_POST['category'];

       foreach ($_POST['wo_num_and_date'] as $k => $v) {
           $wo_num_and_date = $_POST['wo_num_and_date'][$k];
           $comp_name_and_num = $_POST['comp_name_and_num'][$k];
           $finish_sizes = $_POST['finish_sizes'][$k];
           $material = $_POST['material'][$k];
           $total_num_pieces = $_POST['total_num_pieces'][$k];
           $workorder_num_one = $_POST['workorder_num_one'][$k];
           $notes_one = $_POST['notes_one'][$k];
           $workorder_num_two = $_POST['workorder_num_two'][$k];
           $notes_two = $_POST['notes_two'][$k];
           $workorder_num_three = $_POST['workorder_num_three'][$k];
           $notes_three = $_POST['notes_three'][$k];


        $sql = "INSERT INTO checklist_revision (job_num, user_id, revision_num, category, posted_date, per_workorder_number)
        VALUES ($job_num,
                $loggedin_id,
                $revision,
                $category,
                STR_TO_DATE('$posted_date', '%Y-%m-%d'),
                $per_wo_num);";

         mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql);


        $revision_id = mysqli_insert_id($dbc3);

        $sql2 = "INSERT INTO checklist_component_stock (revision, job_num, category, posted_date, wo_num_and_date, comp_name_and_number, finish_sizes, material, total_num_pieces, workorder_num_one, notes_one, signoff_user_one, workorder_num_two, notes_two, signoff_user_two, workorder_num_three, notes_three, signoff_user_three)
        VALUES ('$revision_id',
                '$job_num',
                '$category',
                STR_TO_DATE('$posted_date', '%Y-%m-%d'),
                '$wo_num_and_date',
                '$comp_name_and_num',
                '$finish_sizes',
                '$material',
                '$total_num_pieces',
                '$workorder_num_one',
                '$notes_one',
                NULL,
                '$workorder_num_two',
                '$notes_two',
                NULL,
                '$workorder_num_three',
                '$notes_three',
                NULL);";

         mysqli_query($dbc3, $sql2);    
       }
}
```

Comment: I'm getting errors, where do I put the closing bracket for the for loop ?

Comment: Getting these errors Huseyin,  Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/toolplas/public_html/main/phplib/add_checklist.php on line 24,  Notice: Undefined variable: sql2 in /home/toolplas/public_html/main/phplib/add_checklist.php on line 75, Warning: mysqli_query(): Empty query in /home/toolplas/public_html/main/phplib/add_checklist.php on line 7

Comment: I have forgot to add closing bracket. I am anlyzing your errors now;

Comment: Could you please put `var_dump($_POST)` in if condition to what form names are sent.

Comment: I put it after the for loop closing bracket, please see original post as its too long to post as comment.

Comment: Have you put `[]` after the form elements name as I stated in my answer? It seems your html form names still same.

Comment: Ahh totally forgot to do that for my "Add Button" jquery as well. Thanks for the help it all works now!

Comment: This answer is _bad_ because ot is not using a prepared statement.   I cannot use this page to close new questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example:

```
<form action="" method='post'>
    <input type="text" name="myData[row1]" value='aaa'>
    <input type="text" name="myData[row2]" value='sss'>
    <input type="text" name="myData[row3]" value='ddd'>

    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $array = $_POST['myData'];

    echo "<pre>";
    echo print_r($array);
    echo "</pre>";

    //insert 3 times,
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (info) VALUES('$value')";
    }
}

OUTPUT:
Array
(
    [row1] => aaa
    [row2] => sss
    [row3] => ddd
)
```

Answer (score 0):

*you should remove the `;` like as*

***your code: (INSERT INTO checklist_revision)***

```
VALUES ($job_num,
        $loggedin_id,
        $revision,
        $category,
        STR_TO_DATE('$posted_date', '%Y-%m-%d'), -- -> you should not give like this you should mention the `colname`
        $per_wo_num);";
```

***your should change like:***

```
VALUES ($job_num,
        $loggedin_id,
        $revision,
        $category,
        STR_TO_DATE('$posted_date', '%Y-%m-%d'),
        $per_wo_num)";
```

***your code:(INSERT INTO checklist_component_stock)***

```
 NULL,
    '$workorder_num_three',
    '$notes_three',
    NULL);";
```

***you should change like this:***

```
 NULL,
    '$workorder_num_three',
    '$notes_three',
    NULL)";
```

Comment: Your answer would be great if it was commentary. Because, OP wants to insert multiple row dynamically. Your answer provides typo issue

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL, where is typo issue

Comment: I mean, you should remove `;` . Type or syntax issue. But, OP wants to insert multiple dynamic rows to db.